# Passing an argument to main that calls a function in python

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to pass arguments to my python script using argparse and consequently call functions. Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

```
def parse_args():
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument('-d','--d', dest='action', action='store_const',const=do_comparison, 
                        help="Diff the current and most recent map file memory information)")   

      options = parser.parse_args()

      return options

def do_comparison(parsed_args):
    # do things


def main(args):    
    options = parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: What is going wrong?  What do you expect to happen?  Your use of `argparse` looks fine (at least on the surface).  You just aren't doing anything with the `options` variable in `main`.

Comment: The indentation of the 'if __name__' line is off.  Is that a typo or in the code?

Comment: @hpaulj How would I use options to call do_comp is my question. When I run script.py -d, nothing happens.

Comment: @hpaulj and yes typo

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `store_const` really expects a _constant_ to be provided to `dest`. Why don't you use `store_true` (with a `default` of _False_), and after you parse the args just add: `if options.dest: do_comparison(some_args)`? Or maybe you want to use [callback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#option-callbacks)?

Comment: AttributeError: Namespace object has no attribute 'dest'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment I missed the fact that you are using `store_const` and `const=do_comparison`.  So you are trying some sort of callback.

`options` from `parse_args` is a `argparse.Namespace` object.  This is a simple object, similar to a dictionary.  In fact `vars(options)` returns a dictionary.

When `main` is run (with `-d`), `options.action` will be set to the const, a function.  But remember, in Python, functions are first class objects, and can be set to variables, etc just like numbers and strings.  To be used the function has to be 'called'.

```
options.action()
```

should end up calling `do_comparison`.  Actually since that function requires an argument, you should use

```
options.action(options)
```

or some other way of providing a varible or object to the function.

Of course you'll have to be careful about the case where you don't specify `-d`.  Then `options.action` will have the default value (e.g. `None`).  If the default isn't a callable, then this call will produce an error.

The `argparse` documentation illustrates this kind of action in the section dealing with subparsers (subcommands).  I vaguely recall a tutorial that set an argument value to functions like `add` and `multiply`, creating a simple arithmetic expression evaluator.

Usually the values in the Namespace are strings, or numbers, and to use them you test for string equality.  e.g.

```
 if options.action is None:
     # default action
 elif options.action == 'print':
     print(options)
 else:
     do some other backup or error
```

A callback kind of action is possible, and may be convenient in some cases, but it isn't the usual arrangement.

---

You asked about using `successfully store a string following the -d, to be used as the function arg` with:

```
parser.add_argument('-d','--d', dest='action', dest='function_input', action='store_const', const=diff_map)
```

A 'store_const' action does not take an argument (in effect `nargs=0`).  It's more like `store_true`.  In fact `store_true` is just a `store_const` with has `default=False` and `const=True`.

What you need is another argument, whick could occur either before or after the `-d`.  `argparse` tries to be order flexible.

Here's a simple script with a callable argument, and flexible positional argument.

```
import argparse
def action1(*args):
 print 'action1',args
def action0(*args):
 print 'action0',args

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-d', dest='action', action='store_const', const=action1, default=action0)
parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()
args.action(args.args)
```

resulting runs

```
1238:~/mypy$ python stack32214076.py 
action0 ([],)
1238:~/mypy$ python stack32214076.py one two three
action0 (['one', 'two', 'three'],)
1238:~/mypy$ python stack32214076.py one two three -d
action1 (['one', 'two', 'three'],)
1239:~/mypy$ python stack32214076.py -d one two three
action1 (['one', 'two', 'three'],)
1239:~/mypy$ python stack32214076.py -d
action1 ([],)
```

---

TO make `-d value` perform some action on value, try:

```
parser.add_argument('-d','--action')
```

The default action type stores one value (e.g. action='store', nargs=None)

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.action:  # or is not None
     do_comparison(args.action)
```

If `-d` is not given `args.action` will have default `None` value, and nothing happens here.

If `-d astr` is given `acts.action` will have the string value `'astr'`.  This `if` just calls the `do_comparison` function with this value.  It's the present of this (nondefault) value that triggers the function call.

This is a rather straight forward use of a parser and an argument.

Comment: Quick follow-up. 
parser.add_argument('-d','--d', dest='action', dest='function_input', action='store_const', const=diff_map)

Would this successfully store a string following the -d, to be used as the function arg?

Comment: Below I've specified options.action(function_input) in main.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up, but I maybe have worded my extension incorrectly. I want the -d option to be coupled with the arg following it.

Example. python script.py -d PATH_to_directory

path to directory is then passed to the function coupled with the -d option. If path to directory isn't specified, then error message is displayed.

Comment: Sounds like you just want a normal argument that stores its value.

Comment: separate from the -d?

Comment: Storing both a string (other value) and a callable (function) with the same `-d` argument would require a custom `Action` class.  Or maybe a custom `type` function.  Maybe also the `append` class.  In any case it requires some trickery.